# Étiquettes pour les variantes régionales

Tags: discussion, tags

Quelles étiquettes utiliser pour les variantes régionales du français ?

Il faudra au moins des étiquettes pour les pays ou régions francophones à l'échelle mondiale. Il y a déjà [quebec](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quebec) et [afrique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afrique), et sur ce modèle il pourrait apparaître [belgique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgique), [france](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france), etc. On pourrait préférer un autre style de nommage comme [quebecois](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quebecois) ou [francais-quebecois](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/francais-quebecois) ou [francais-du-quebec](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/francais-du-quebec) (à ne pas confondre avec [francais-de-quebec](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/francais-de-quebec) !). À une échelle plus locale, nous avons déjà [parler-lyonnais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parler-lyonnais).

Il faudrait peut-être aussi une étiquette pour les questions plus génériques sur les variations régionales. Nous avons actuellement [regional](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional) et [regionalismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regionalismes) (à synonymiser, clairement, mais dans quel sens ?), et [dialecte](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialecte) a fait une apparition à un moment.

La page de Wikipédia sur les [variétés régionales du français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s_r%C3%A9gionales_du_fran%C3%A7ais) donne une idée de la variété à couvrir. Nous n'aurons pas forcément autant d'étiquettes qu'il y a d'entrées sur cette page, par exemple le site [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) ne descend pas en-dessous du niveau de `british-english`, `indian-english`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Je suis assez partisan de la simplicité : sur FL&U, [quebec](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quebec) et autres devraient être assez clair, surtout avec le wiki pour expliquer de quoi il s'agit. Pour les limites de régions qu'on considère je pense qu'on verra à l'usage : le questionneur met l'étiquette de la portée qui lui semble pertinente, quitte à ce que ce soit précisé ou étendu par la suite, à moyen terme on devrait avoir des limites convenables.

Avec le même raisonnement de simplicité, je suis plutôt pour [regional](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional).

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement j'opterais pour « régionalismes », simplement parce que comme tous les autres tags c'est un nom. Avec l'autre choix, on pourrait se demander ce qui est « régional ». Est-ce la question ? le contenu ? les réponses ?

Bref, et c'est surtout par souci d'uniformité, il me semble que [regional](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional) → [regionalismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regionalismes) est préférable.